# mi row.add no esta funcionado en una llamada ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, datatables

Actualmente quiero llenar mi datatable con una llamada ajax que va al codebehind de C# y ese codebehind retorna una lista de arreglos y hago iteraciones con cada uno de los items de la lista para obtenr los arreglos y dichos arreglos meterlos como registros, pero simplemente se queda vacia la datatable.

LLamada ajax:

```
function getRecords(idExcel, tipoFile) {
    $("#IdRecords").removeClass("d-none");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Admin.aspx/getInforRecords",
        data: '{idUpload:"' + idExcel + '",tipoFile:"' + tipoFile + '"}',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            $.each(result.d, function (index, value) {
                Table.rows.add(value).draw();
            });
                Table.draw();

            return;
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(error)
        }
    });
}
```

Codebehind de C#:

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<string[]> getInforRecords(int idUpload, int tipoFile)
{
    UploadGEOController geocont = new UploadGEOController();
    List<List<string>> listgeo = new List<List<string>>();
    string htmlreturn = "";

    listgeo = geocont.RecordsExcel(idUpload, tipoFile);
    List<string[]> data = new List<string[]>();


    foreach (List<string> elemento in listgeo)
    {
        string[] arrays = new string[5];
        arrays[0] = elemento[1];
        arrays[1] = elemento[2];
        arrays[2] = elemento[3];
        arrays[3] = elemento[4];
        arrays[4] = "<div class='col-lg-12 text-center' ><i id='ModalRecords' class='fa fa-info  Tooltip-Info' title='Aqui podra ver el detalle en especificacion'   aria-hidden='true' style='cursor:pointer;' onclick='getRecordsEspecified(\"" + elemento[0] + "\");' data-featherlight='#fl1' ></i></div>";
        data.Add(arrays);
    }


    return data;

}
```

¿Estoy realizando algo del llenado mal?

Comment: si pones un breakpoint en el codigo puede evaluar que `geocont.RecordsExcel()` retorna alguna respuesta con datos ?

Comment: lo que noto es que los tipos de datos que usas `List<List<string>>` y `List<string[]>` son basicamente los mismo para `json` se lo retorna directo sin recorrer nada en javascript se procesa como array